# Selenium ide: Find the highlighted tab on an application

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a tabbed navigation application with three tabs (tab1, tab2 and tab3)in a linear fashion and each of it gets highlighted if I am on it. I need to find out if the tab I am on right now is highlighted and assert its title.

for Example if I am on tab2-- it gets highlighted and its class changes to

```
class="tracker__item ng-scope ng-binding tracker__item_current"
```

The other two tabs remain as

```
class="tracker__item ng-scope ng-binding"
```

I need to capture this "__item_current" and write a command to verify it and return true and also assert that current tab is tab2.

Only Selenium IDE- I am not familiar with web driver. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write an `xpath` expression:

```
//*[@class="tracker__item" and @class="tracker__item_current"]
```